# How to treat each souce file as a separate program in MSVC

Tags: c, visual-c++

Can I configure MSVC to treat every source file as a separate program within a single project?

For example:

Source file one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    printf("This is program one");
    return 0;
}
```

Source file two:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    printf("This is program two");
    return 0;
}
```

Currently when I compile I get a linker error telling me that `_main` is already defined.

Comment: You might use a *builder* like [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) and compile thru command line. If you compile on a command line, please show that command.

Comment: Thanks for the great idea. I will combine my old workflow with the new one. Before I was doing everything in a cygwin terminal(editing in nano and compiling with ```cc```). Now I'll do my C work in MSVC and compile with cygwin. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, if you are familiar with `make` can't you install and use Linux?

Comment: I though of that when I started but I use Windows on my computer and installing Linux in a vm for writing a few programs felt a bit unnecessary but as the programs grew I needed some assistance(error checking, etc), I also had cygwin installed so why not use that.

Comment: Why do you need Windows (for games?)? I never used it (and my first program was in 1974, punched cards, PL/1 I was 15 then)

Comment: I wish I could switch over to linux but the programs I use(Premiere pro, After Effects and some others in that line of work) dont exist for Linux.

Comment: You can't.  The source files in a project, after compilation, are only subjected to a single linker step and can thus produce only a single executable image.  You can technically hack a post build event that runs the linker to get the second executable.  But that's pretty deep off the far end, considering that the alternative is so simple.  Just create another project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Projects in Visual Studio generate *one executable*. When you create a project you have one solution. You need to add *another* project to the same solution.

Assuming you want create fresh server and client project, you can do it as the following:

- Create a new project, set the project ***Name*** to ***Server*** and the ***Solution*** to ***ServerClientApp***.
- Add `main.c` into Server's ***Source Files*** and implement `main.c`.

Now you've created a solution with one project. You can add another project as the following:

- Right click on ***Solution 'ServerClientApp' (1 project)*** from the ***Solution Explorer*** window, and click on ***Add*** -> ***New Project***, and set the project ***Name*** to ***Client***.
- Add `main.c` to Client's ***Source Files*** and write `main.c`.

You can now build all these projects by right clicking on Solution ***Solution ServerClientApp' (2 projects)*** from the ***Solution Explorer***, and click on ***Build Solution***.

The generated executables can be found at `ServerClientApp\debug`.